# Is the computation of a certain limit beyond Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am surprised the following computation stumps Mathematica:

```
Limit[
  (2^((1 - n)/2) x^(-1 + 1/2 (-1 + n)) E^(-((x n)/(2 V))) 
    (V/n)^((1 - n)/2))/Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)], 
  n -> ∞]
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I missing something that can assist Mathematica?

Comment: For me works fine:`Limit[(2^((1 - n)/2) x^(-1 + 1/2 (-1 + n)) E^(-((x n)/(2 V))) (V/
       n)^((1 - n)/2))/Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)], n -> \[Infinity], 
 Assumptions -> {x > 0, V > 0}]` gives:0

Comment: That was strange. I copied your code and Mathematica couldn't do it. What do you get when you specifically set V = 1?

Comment: Executing code on MMA v12.0 `Limit[(2^((1 - n)/2) x^(-1 + 1/2 (-1 + n)) E^(-((x n)/(2 V))) (V/
        n)^((1 - n)/2))/Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)] /. V -> 1, 
 n -> \[Infinity]]` give me: `ConditionalExpression[0, x > 1 + Log[x]]`

Comment: My version is 11.1.1.0

Comment: In 11.3, I get: ConditionalExpression[0, x/V + Log[V] > 1 + Log[x]]

Answer (score 1):

With Mathematica 11.3 running MacOS 10.13.4, I get

```
Limit[
  (2^((1 - n)/2) x^(-1 + 1/2 (-1 + n)) E^(-((x n)/(2 V))) 
    (V/n)^((1 - n)/2))/Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)], 
   n -> ∞]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[0, x/V + Log[V] > 1 + Log[x]]`

which indicates that

```
Limit[
  (2^((1 - n)/2) x^(-1 + 1/2 (-1 + n)) E^(-((x n)/(2 V))) 
    (V/n)^((1 - n)/2))/Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)], 
  n -> ∞,
  Assumptions -> x/V + Log[V] > 1 + Log[x]]
```

will give 0, which it does. You might try this 2nd form on your system.